Two-week vacation with water off at main - gas water heater to "pilot" at ignition and/or "pilot lighting mode"?
I'll be gone for two weeks during winter in an area that's subject to freezing. I'll leave my furnace on at 60 degrees. I want to turn the water off at the street main. In the basement, I have a natural gas water heater without an expansion tank, and I've seen a lot of contradictory advice about "turning it to pilot." Can you please help clarify?
There is a small dial that includes "on" "off" and "pilot" used when lighting the pilot. There is also a larger dial controlling temperature, and the lowest setting is called "pilot lighting". There is no vac or vacation setting. The manual says pilot lighting is 45 degrees.
When folks say "put it on pilot," are they saying to do this at the ignition "on" "off" "pilot" dial??? Or is the advice more like "pilot lighting" on the thermostat dial -- or both? My manual is not helpful on what to do beyond full shutdown and draining if leaving to an unspecified "extended period of time."
Can you please clarify the recommendation?

the safest solution is to leave everything on, just reduce the heater setting. It is made to work 24/7 anyway.

I would turn off the heater and drain the water pipes.  If it gets cold enough and something happens to the heat, the pipes can burst if they freeze.  They would need replacing/repairing before turning the water back on.

"Pilot" is a setting used to turn on the gas.
In a water heater, gravity furnace or other device that does not take electricity... when the big flame kicks on, what lights it?  The answer is some gas is constantly supplied to a "pilot flame" set up to light the main burner.

OK, but what if that "pilot flame" burns out?  We can't have the thing dumping gas into the home, slowly filling it with gas until KABLAMMO.
So the safety device is a pilot valve.  It is positioned so the warmth of the pilot acts on a "bi-metal strip" which is bent by the heat, holding the pilot valve open.  If the pilot goes out, the bi-metal strip cools off and closes the pilot valve, stopping gas.
Fantastic.  But hold on.  How do we initially light the pilot?  The bimetal strip will be cold, and will be holding the pilot valve off.
The answer is a middle position called "Pilot". When in that position, you are allowed to ALSO push the button inward, and it will flow gas so you can light the pilot.  You must continue holding it for a half minute or so until the bimetal strip warms enough to hold the valve open on its own.

That's what "turn to pilot" is for. All that to say, you're better off just turning the water heater to the "OFF" position and then relighting it when you return.

Thank you for the information! It helps to understand the appliance better.

If you are turning off water to the entire house (in my area the "street main" is supposed to be for water company use only, though plumbers use it in an emergency, but most houses have a valve at the house that serves the same purpose, and the pipe in the ground from street to house normally doesn't have a freezing problem) then you should also turn off the water heater.
Why? Because if something went wrong - water heater leaked, some pipe inside the house did freeze, etc. - then your water heater might drain. It wouldn't cause a huge flood, because your main water supply would be off. But it might leave the water heater empty while continuing to heat. In the case of an electric water heater, that would burn out the element(s). In the case of a gas water heater, it could damage the water heater and possibly start a fire.
There doesn't need to be an "off" setting on a water heater, though I think there usually is one, because it is normally always on. But turn off the gas valve before the water heater and it is now off. Similarly, for an electric water heater you can turn off the breaker.

Thanks! I do have an off setting that turns off the flow of gas.
